# Reading Google Sheet File From Shared Drive

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need to read a `Google Sheet` file from a shared Drive with a `Node.js` script that runs with a cronjob.
The sheet is updated periodically with `Zapier` (none related to the issue).

I use a token that looks like that:
(this works when I try to read field from `Drive` but I can't see their content)

```
    var token = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"],
        null
    )
```

I tried 2 ways:

1. using the Google API sheets functions:

```
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', token});
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: GSHEET_ID,
        range:null
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;
        if (rows.length) {
          // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
          rows.map((row) => {
            console.log(row);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No data found.');
        }
      });
```

I am getting an error:

```
The API returned an error: Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/spreadsheets/GSHEET_ID/values/</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

2. Google Drive API:

```
    var drive = google.drive("v3");

    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('../user_response.csv');
    const res = await drive.files.export(
        {
            auth: token,
            fileId:GSHEET_ID,
            mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'},
        {responseType: 'stream'}
      );
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.data
          .on('error', reject)
          .pipe(dest)
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('finish', resolve);
      });
```

I am getting an error: `code 400 - Bad Request`.

These are the scopes I am using:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly

Is there another way I can try to solve this issue?

In addition,
I have a field in the spreadsheet: "Updated".
After reading a row where Updated == false, I'll want to update it to true.
How can I edit this field when the spreadsheet is in `Google Drive`?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Although I can understand your 1st question. unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do about your 2nd question of `In addition, I have a field in the spreadsheet: "Updated". After reading a row where Updated == false, I'll want to update it to true. How can I edit this field when the spreadsheet is in Google Drive?`. So, can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question?

Comment: The spreadsheet headers are ['id', 'user', 'updated']. When I read the spreadsheet from the Drive I look for rows where the value of 'updated' is False and I process the data in them. After I process the data I want to change the value of 'updated' to True. (automatically in the code not manually)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your question, I could understand the reason for the issue with your 2 scripts. But, I cannot still understand your 3rd question from `The spreadsheet headers are ['id', 'user', 'updated']. When I read the spreadsheet from the Drive I look for rows where the value of 'updated' is False and I process the data in them. After I process the data I want to change the value of 'updated' to True. (automatically in the code not manually)`. What is `I process the data in them`?

Comment: You can't export a sheet with the `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. It has to be one of the [compatible export formats](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats?hl=en)

Comment: Is there a way to convert Google Sheet to CSV with code?

Comment: You need to download each sheet individually from the Spreadsheet. You can fetch the following URL where `ssid` is your Spreadsheet ID and `sid` is the gid of the sheet you wish to download: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ssid/export?format=csv&gid=sid`